# create a simple (and visible!) UI slider in Unity 5

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider

![enter image description here][1]please I need some help, this should apparently be something very simple and basic to do, but maybe I'm missing something.

I'm quite newbie to Unity3d, I had no much problem with creating a somewhat flashy 2.D scene (I mean 2D with different layers in Z level), scripts, etc. But I'm having trouble to create a "UI Slider" object: when I create it, it just shows nothing on screen. How can I make it visible? I just need to create a very simple, plain slider whose value can be controlled at runtime by means of a script.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. since you give nothing to go on, I suggest that you take a look at a tutorial for the UI:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/using-the-ui-tools

If you have troubles after this tutorial, come back with an example of your problem to make people more willing to sacrifice their time in helping you.

Hope this is somewhat useful

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Unity3D docs here.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Slider.html

It should have what you are looking for.

Comment: I managed to solved part of the problem. Initially I couldn't find it because its container Canvas was massively large and located elsewhere instead of around my scene. To solve this, I set the "Render Camera" attribute of the Canvas object to my Main Camera. Now however, the slider is created within my scene area, but it is not really visible: actually this happens for buttons and other UI elements. I only see the empty "cursor rectangle" whenever I have the slider object selected in my hierarchy

Comment: okay.... completely solved now. The issue was, again in the associated Canvas, not in the UI element itself. By default, it had a Z position of 90 ???? so I had to adjust it so that the slider were not behind my scene background image. thanks!